# How to remove rows in a dataset by matching a column in another dataset

Tags: r, dataset, match, subset

I'm very new to coding and am struggling with some data processing. I want to remove rows from a dataset based on another dataset. The datasets are fairly large and I am unable to match it accurately. The first dataset, dat1, is:

```
userId  showId
user1     1
user1     3
user2     2
user3     1
user3     3
```

The second dataset, dat2, contains show Ids and attribute such as genre in the other columns

```
showId genre
1       a
2       b
3       a
4       b
5       b
```

I want to delete the rows in Dataset 2 where the `showId` does not appear in dataset. (i.e., i want to remove information about shows which are not in dataset 1 from dataset 2). I've tried:

```
nl <- subset(unique(dat1$showId) %in% dat2$showId)
```

Since I have 3 unique `showIds` in `dat1`, I should have 3 rows in object `nl` but this does not work and it returns me with rows =/= the number of unique `showIds` in dat1. Does anyone know any other way I can do this? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `subset` typically requires a data frame as input, not a logical vector. What happens if you add dat1 as the first argument to subset?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
df2[!is.na(match(df2$showId, df1$showId)),]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  showId genre
   <dbl> <chr>
1      1 a    
2      2 b    
3      3 a
```

Comment: this works better, but I'm still missing 6 values. Thank you for this though!

Comment: @Karthik S Hello, I tried this code out but it seems only to count matches between same-line observations. Is there a way to modify it so that it counts matches beyond same-line observations? so if row 5 of Data2 matches *any* row of Data 1$showID, it is kept. Thank you.

Comment: @hongpastry, `match` function looks for matches independent of row positions, if you can ask a question with sample data, then I can look into it.

Answer (score 0):

One option that works and should be easy to follow and use in other cases would be:

```
# Create a filter based on unique values in showId of dat1
filter_dat2 <- unique(dat1$showId)

# Filter dat2 to just those showId values that are in dat1
dat2_limited <- dat2 %>% filter(showId %in% filter_dat2)
```

This gives the following result:

```
  showId genre
1      1     a
2      2     b
3      3     a
```

Hope that might help.